# What is the difference between URLLoader and URLRequest in Actionscript?

Tags: actionscript, urlloader, urlrequest

What is the difference between URLLoader and URLRequest in Actionscript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`URLRequest` prepares a url to be used by any service in Flash that needs to communicate with a server, capturing all of the information in a single HTTP request.

The `URLLoader`, on the other hand, is used to download data from a URL as text, binary data, or URL-encoded variables.